# Date time conversion in R

Tags: r, date, time

I know similar things have been discussed but here's a few things I haven't found answers yet.

## 1: Date to POSIXct

```
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "EST"

> as.POSIXct("2011-01-30")
[1] "2011-01-30 EST"

> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-01-30"))
[1] "2011-01-29 19:00:00 EST"

> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-01-30"), tz="EST")
[1] "2011-01-29 19:00:00 EST"

> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-01-30"), tz="GMT")
[1] "2011-01-29 19:00:00 EST"

> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-01-30"), tz="America/New_York")
[1] "2011-01-29 19:00:00 EST"

> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-01-30"), tz="")
[1] "2011-01-29 19:00:00 EST"
```

Can anybody tell me why, if the input is a Date, I cannot get midnight January 30 even though I specified the correct time zone?  While if the input is character string then I'm OK.

## 2: Date/Character conversion.

Both are horribly slow.  Then I found that to convert a character string to a Date it's actually a lot faster by converting it to POSIXlt first:

```
> d3.str = "2011-03-02 23:59:00";
> N=10000
> system.time(for(i in 1:N) r5.dt = as.Date(d3.str))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.25    0.00    1.24 
> system.time(for(i in 1:N) r6.dt = as.Date(strptime(d3.str, format="%Y-%m-%d")))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.37    0.00    0.38 
> r5.dt
[1] "2011-03-02"
> r5.dt==r6.dt
[1] TRUE
```

I'm now confused.  Is there any faster, more elegant way to convert a character to a Date?  And a Date to a character instead as.character which is also quite slow?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey Gavin, thanks for editing!  It looks much better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for your second question, a lot will probably be clearer if you compare the code for `as.Date.character` and `as.Date.POSIXlt`. One of them has to do a lot more checking of stuff since you haven't specified a format.

As for general speed, you aren't vectorizing your conversions. `as.Date` and `strptime` and most other Date/Time conversion functions accept *vectors* of dates and DateTimes. It will be considerably faster than way.

Comment: Leap-seconds are added at the turn of the year and DST changes have never occurred in January, so I think you should strike your last sentence.

Comment: I just figured out similar functions like as.character.Date, as.POSIXlt.POSIXct etc., and generally specifying the format speeds up things a lot.  In my situation I have to use a loop.  This is great stuff, thank everybody for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Very early in the as.POSIXct help page we read: "Dates without times are treated as being at midnight UTC." Your expectation that the 'tz' argument will modify this is simply mistaken. You can get the original date if you specify the *output* to be in UCT:

```
 strftime(as.POSIXct(as.Date("2011-01-30")), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UCT")
#[1] "2011-01-30 00:00:00"
```

If you really just want a date then you should use `as.Date`.

Comment: +1 -- and if you want midnight in your time zone, use `ISODatetime(2012,1,11,0,0,0)` (or any other date).

Comment: Thanks for that. It would be good to note that `srtftime` creates a 'character' result, while `ISOdatetime` (note that the "d" is not capped) returns class 'POSIXct', so it may be more desirable.

Answer (score 2):

The `tz` argument of as.POSIXct is only used with strings, and (silently) ignored otherwise. You may want to look at packages designed to help manipulate dates, e.g., the `with_tz` function in the `lubridate` package.